# Best project structure for django & angularjs

Tags: python, angularjs, django

I create a pretty big Django project for my own and want to implement AngularJS on frontend and some rest framework on backend. I know that the project will implement at least 7-8 my own apps (I think that django apps should be small and responsible for one functionality).

I've never used AngularJS before - but I want to create good architecture.
So just one django app should have one angular app?

```
| - Django project
|--- app1
|------ angular_app1
|---------angular controller1
|---------angular controller2
|--- app2
|------ angular_app2
|---------angular controller1
|---------angular controller2
```

Or maybe I should have one global angular app for whole project and single django apps should register theirs controllers in view? I think that it can be usefull when we want to use a module from other app.

```
| - Django project
|--- angular app
|--- app1
|-------angular controller1
|-------angular controller2
|--- app2
|-------angular controller3
|-------angular controller4
```

Or maybe I'm still wrong?

Answer (score 5):

I actually recently built a huge application using Django and AngularJS.

I used DRF for the rest services. Going through the architecture, i decided to serve Angular within the context of Django itself. So my project structure looked like follows

```
| - Django project
    --DjangoApp1
    --DjangoApp2
    --DjangoSettingsDir
    --static
        --assets/
            --JS/
                -- controllers/
            --partials/
    --templates //base Django templates
         --index.html
```

Served `index.html` at `/` using simple Django `render`. Used Angular, UI Router, UI  Bootstrap etc within `index.html` to build the app.

Comment: Whole project was SPA? 
I thought about 1 django app = 1 django view (template i mean) and all of subviews make with Angular. What you think?

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I've done. Added a `Ui-view` directive in the main template and used it from there.

Comment: Assuming you are using npm like tools for development, How do you deploy your js static files on production server?

Answer (score 0):

```
`| - Django project
--DjangoApp1
--DjangoApp2
--DjangoSettingsDir
--static
    --bower_component/
        --all Javascript Library/
    --node_build
        --all node files or npm files(if required)
    --templates
        --all custom HTML files
    --JavaScript
        --all custom JavaScript files
    --Style
        --all custom CSS files goes here
--templates //base Django templates
     --index.html`
     --index.js
     --index.css
```